# Python variable weirdness?

Tags: python, list, variables, reference, tuples

What's going on with my Python variable? `old_pos` seems to be linked to `pos`:

Code:

```
pos = [7, 7]
direction = [1, 1]
old_pos = pos
print 'pos     = '+str(pos)
print 'old_pos = '+str(old_pos)
pos[0] += direction[0]
pos[1] += direction[1]
print 'pos     = '+str(pos)
print 'old_pos = '+str(old_pos)
```

Output:

```
pos     = [7, 7]
old_pos = [7, 7]
pos     = [8, 8]
old_pos = [8, 8]
```

---

However, if I replace `old_pos = pos` with `old_pos = tuple(pos)` or even `old_pos = list(pos)`, I don't get this problem:

```
pos     = [7, 7]
old_pos = [7, 7]
pos     = [8, 8]
old_pos = [7, 7]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what `=` does.  :-)

Comment: there are no variables in python, only names and objects.

Comment: @hop: But aren't the names reference variables?

Comment: @recursive: It depends on how you define "variables", but it's usually easier to think about if you don't consider Python names to be the same thing as variables. See: http://www.python.net/crew/mwh/hacks/objectthink.html

Comment: "There are no variables in Python" is a silly confusing slogan.  You mean, "variables in Python work differently than in C."

Comment: So why would you ever want two names for the same object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you say `old_pos = pos`, you are not creating a copy of `pos`, but just making another reference to the same list.  If you want two lists that behave independently, you'll need to make a copy, like using the `list(pos)` function as you mention, or using the slice notation `pos[:]`.

Answer (score 7):

`old_pos = pos` does not create a copy of the object refered to by the name `pos`, rather it creates a second reference called `old_pos` to the very same object.  Actions done to `pos` affect the same object referred to by `old_pos`.  In the same way, the names "Steven" and "Mr. Rumbalski" both refer to me.  If you punch Steven in the face, Mr. Rumbalski will be injured, because the two names refer to the same object -- me.

Here are 3 ways to make an actual copy instead of a second reference:

Using slice notation

```
old_pos = pos[:]
```

Using the list constructor

```
old_pos = list(pos)
```

Using the copy module

```
from copy import copy
old_pos = copy(pos)
```

Note that these copies are all shallow copies, which in this case is fine.  To learn about the difference between shallow copy and deep copy read the [documentation of the copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).

Answer (score 3):

> `old_pos` seems to be linked to `pos`

Correct - this:

```
old_pos = pos
```

makes `old_pos` and `pos` point to the same list. It doesn't create a new copy of `pos`.

Answer (score 3):

recursive is right about the cause. You can see that they have identical memory addresses:

```
>>> pos = [7, 7]
>>> old_pos = pos
>>> id(pos)
4299304472
>>> id(old_pos)
4299304472
```

This is called *passing by reference*, versus passing by value. You can also remedy this situation by using the `copy` module.

```
>>> from copy import copy
>>> pos = [7, 7]
>>> old_pos = pos
>>> id(pos)
4299304472
>>> id(old_pos)
4299304472
>>> old_pos = copy(pos)
>>> id(old_pos)
4299349240
```

Comment: Um... it's not really *passing by reference* because you're not **passing** anything in the example.  It's just that Python names have *reference semantics* in how they refer to Python objects.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the aforementioned comments, some additional steps must be taken in case of multi dimensional arrays. For instance, when you have a two dimensional array `a = [[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8]]`, the code `b = a` will not create an independent copy. However, it will create another reference to the references of the same one dimensional lists within the two dimensional list. To solve this, you must use one of the aforementioned methods for every list within the two dimensional list. For example, `b = [i[:] for i in a]` will create an independent copy of the list.