# python variables

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment

I have a simple question. i read a string from file and stored in in a list (named:formula). Then i stored (formula) in another variable (fstore = formula) to keep it for later. Then i made changes to formula, and as it turns out, fstore is changing as well. Why does this keep happening? I want fstore to remain constant. I didnt use fstore anywhere else in the program. Is my assignment (fstore = formula) wrong?

Jay

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python variable weirdness?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619368/python-variable-weirdness)

Answer (score 5):

The important distinction here is between *mutable* and *immutable* data types. In python, a list is mutable, while a tuple is immutable. This means that when you "change" the value of a tuple like this:

```
t1 = (1, 2, 3)     # t1 points to (1, 2, 3)
t2 = t1            # t2 points to the same tuple as t1
t1 = (2, 3, 4)     # t1 points to a new tuple (2, 3, 4)
```

you're actually creating a brand new tuple and assigning `t1` to point to that new tuple. `t2` still points to the old tuple, which cannot be changed, because tuples are immutable. In short, if you assign an immutable value to a variable, you can assume that value will never change -- unless you explicitly assign a new value to the variable.

But when you change the value of a list, you actually change the list itself:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]     # l1 points to [1, 2, 3] 
l2 = l1            # l2 points to the same list as l1
l1[0] = 5          # now [1, 2, 3] becomes [5, 2, 3]
```

Since `l1` and `l2` both point to the same list, they both change when one of them changes.

To make a copy that won't change when `l1` changes, simply use `list`:

```
l2 = list(l1)
```

Or use slice notation:

```
l2 = l1[:]
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember that those names in Python aren't VARIABLEs, they're REFERENCES to variables.  So you're ending up with two aliases to one piece of store.  Have a look at the copy module, or use this:

```
 cpy = mystr[:]
```